# How to remove/replace a file with libgcab

Tags: cab

I'm exploring libgcab to do some surgery on a cab/msi file on macOS. This library looks promising it has following calls (reading the .h file):

gcab_cabinet_add_folder
gcab_cabinet_write
gcab_cabinet_extract

but I see no calls to delete files or folders.